# SimpleDateFormat date being parsed incorrectly?

Tags: java, date-format, simpledateformat, date-formatting

So I have some code:

```
String ANNOUNCEMENT_DATE = "Sat, 25-Aug-2014 11:00:00 GMT"; 

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z");

Date announcementDate = null;

try {
    announcementDate = df.parse(announcementDateString);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

announcementEpochTime = announcementDate.getTime()/1000;
```

So, as I expected, up until 11:00:00 today, the following expression resolved to false:

```
System.currentTimeMillis()/1000 >= announcementEpochTime
```

However, after 11:00:00, I expected it to resolve to true...but it doesn't.

I'm looking at the fastTime value of the announcementDate, and it seems to be significantly larger than the current system time, even now (33 minutes later)

when I look at the parsed announcementDate in a debugger I see:

```
 2014-08-25T12:00:00.000+0100
```

which looks wrong to me. I'm sure there's some issue with timezones or some-such, but I can't quite get my head around it.

Any idea why my date being parsed incorrectly?

I know these things are far from trivial problems in many circumstances, so I'm hoping someone will be familiar with these utilities and spot my problem out of hand (and save me half a day of googling frantically)

Comment: Maybe it is a timezone problem?

Comment: you are having year too in your date string again before gmt..
try this ("EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss yyyy z");

Comment: Did you notice that your `SimpleDateFormat` cannot parse the `ANNOUNCEMENT_DATE` variable ? it should be `EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss yyyy z`

Comment: first thing i can see your input string to parse() and the string you specified are different and try using Locale in SimpleDateFormat()

Comment: Division by 1000 seems redundant as they are both in millisecs

Comment: @ortis / Sumeet / SparkOn The second 2014 in my date-format was actually a typo, my apologies. It's fixed now.

Comment: @boxed__l yeah, that's for another calculation later on, I was just trying to twist what I had into a cogent example of the issue I was facing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are obviously living in Ireland with a daylight saving time of +1 hour in summer.

That means, your time 12:00h IST corresponds to 11:00h GMT. And consequently that means: Your assumption will become true at 12:00h local time.

I tested it with this little program and a daylight savin time of +2 hours against GMT (in Germany):

```
public class Time {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ANNOUNCEMENT_DATE1 = "Mon, 25-Aug-2014 10:00:00 GMT";
        String ANNOUNCEMENT_DATE2 = "Mon, 25-Aug-2014 11:00:00 GMT";

        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss z", Locale.ENGLISH);

        Date announcementDate1 = null;
        Date announcementDate2 = null;
        try {
            announcementDate1 = df.parse(ANNOUNCEMENT_DATE1);
            announcementDate2 = df.parse(ANNOUNCEMENT_DATE2);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(now >= announcementDate1.getTime());
        System.out.println(now >= announcementDate2.getTime());
    }
}
```

Running that on 12:54 (local time) results in the following output:

> true
>
> false

Comment: So the core problem is that GMT doesn't factor in Daylight savings time?

Comment: GMT simply doesn't know the concept of daylight savings.

Comment: Great, you nailed it so! I'll use IST and see what happens. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

May be your simpledateformat pattern should be `("EEE, dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss yyyy z")` as you have year before your GMT

Comment: That was a typo, apologies. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

@paul What time-jone your system has?
If it is GMT then only your comparision is valid. otherwise you will have to consider timezone offset in comparision too.